# What would /i at the end of gsub regex mean?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am starting on Ruby and referring to "Begining Ruby From Novice to professional" book. Something that I wasn't able to figure out is the `/i` at the end of this regex means..

```
text.gsub(/\b(You|Me|My|Your)\b/i) do |x|
```

Comment: i makes the regex match case insensitive.

Comment: ...and is referred to as a "modifier".  There are very few such [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html), and `i` is by far the most commonly-used one.

Comment: Read and try on http://rubular.com

Comment: Tried the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html)? Just search (Ctrl + f) for "/i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` modifier is used to perform *case-insensitive* matching. By using this modifier, letters in the pattern match both **upper** and **lower** case. Be sure to check out the Regexp [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html).

Answer (score 0):

i - means 'case insensetive'.

so /a/i matches "A"

You can be interested reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) and play with [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com).

Comment: thanks for the Rubular link, the other link provided does not work. But answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Thats case insensitive
it means no matter if the sentence or even the letter are upper or lower case

like

```
/foobar/i
```

will match for any variation of upper and lower cases of foobar

you can define in some languages (?i:word)
if you want to match just F and B you can or any other letter or word

```
(?i:f)oo(?i:b)ar
```

will match for FooBar or foobar